# Address parts, proper order

Tags: google-maps

if I look up this address:

> Maanweg 174, 2500 BD The Hague, Nederlands

google maps finds it perfectly.  if I look it up this way:

> Maanweg 174, The Hague, Nederlands 2500 BD

It does not, because the postal code is out of place.

Now my question: I have 4 fields: Address, City/Region, Country and Postal Code.  if the user starts to type the address, a lookup on google maps comes up with a list of addresses the user can pick from.  I break the user selection appart and fill-in my 4 fields.

However... if the user changes some part of the address, I need to reconstitute it into a string to feed it to google... but I don't know the proper order.  in the Netherlands, the postal code goes after the address.  in the US it goes at the end, right before the country.

how can I find out what the proper order is?

Answer (score 0):

There is no unique format, you should use the format as it will be used in the particular country (see: https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#geocoder_queryformat )

According to http://www.bitboost.com/ref/international-address-formats/netherlands/ the order of the first example is correct(for the Netherlands).

Comment: I understand each country has its own format.  I guess what I'm asking is how can I discover those formats?  the first link you provide only provides some vague guidelines.  the second link I'm familiar with but it only provides the format for the Netherlands.  I would need something like it for the rest of the countries in the world

Comment: when you know the 2nd link you also should know the main-page : http://www.bitboost.com/ref/international-address-formats.html

Comment: seems like a project for someone (possibly me on a day when I've got nothing better to do, ha!) to collect all that information and make it available in some usable way to developers